# How can I create a system that tells me if still have available slots with 2 given parameters

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

For my assigntment I need to create an order system, that assigns time slots based on free capacity.
I can choose the number of slots `int numberOfTimeSlots` and the capacity per slot `int capacityPerSlot` (so if I have 3 slots and 3 capacity per slot, that's 9 slots in total).

Each customer states their preferred time slot `int preferredSlot` (here: 0, 1 or 2) with their order.

I need to check if there is still capacity left in their desired slot, before I can place the order.
If there is capacity left I assign them their preferred slot. If there is no capacity left I assign them a slot with the next lowest index to their preferred one. If there is no slot left at all, I return nothing.

This is my attempt using two ArrayLists:

```java
int givenSlot = 0, count = 0;

public Optional<Integer> addOrder(Order order, int preferredSlot) {
    List<Integer> slots = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> slotsPerSlot = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if ((slots.size() * slotsPerSlot.size()) <= (numberOfTimeSlots * capacityPerSlot)) {
        if (slots.contains(preferredSlot) == false) {
            givenSlot = preferredSlot;
            slots.add(preferredSlot);
            slotsPerSlot.add(count);
            count++;
        } else if (slotsPerSlot.size() <= capacityPerSlot) {
            givenSlot = preferredSlot;
            slots.add(preferredSlot);
            slotsPerSlot.add(slotsPerSlot.size() + 1);
        } else {
            givenSlot = slots.get(slots.lastIndexOf(count));
        }
        return Optional.of(givenSlot);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

I've also tried to use an ArrayList with a 2D-Array:

```java
int givenSlot = 0, count = 0;

public Optional<Integer> addOrder(Order order, int preferredSlot) {
    ArrayList<Integer> slots = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[][] slotsPerSlot = new int[numberOfTimeSlots][capacityPerSlot];

    if (!slots.contains(preferredSlot)) {
        givenSlot = preferredSlot;
        slots.add(preferredSlot);
        slotsPerSlot[preferredSlot] = new int[count];
        count++;
    } else if (slotsPerSlot.length < 0) {

    }
```

I also experimented with two Arrays, Hashmap or a list in a list, but I always run across the same problem:
I don't know how I can get the capacity per slot for each slot and that's way I can't progress with my code at all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how how exactly you're modelling your slots and capacity. If only the remaining capacity is needed all you'd need is an array of integers, e.g. `int[] remainingCap = new int[]{3,3,3};` and whenever a customer takes a slot you decrement the respective element. When looking for remaining capacity you look for any element/slot with a value > 0.

If you need some more information on a slot you might want to introduce a class:

```
class Slot {
  private final String name;
  private final int capacity; //total capacity
  private int remainingCapacity; //what's remaining

  public Slot( String name, int cap) {
    this.name = name;
    this.capacity = cap;
    this.remainingCapacity = cap;
  }

  //add setters/getters
}
```

Then build an array, e.g. `Slot[] slots = new Slot[]{new Slot("first", 3), new Slot("second", 3), ...);`, and work on those.

Finally, if you also need to know who took a slot to be able to free it you might need more classes.

Example:

```
class Reservation {
  private Customer customer; //who took the reservation or null 

  public boolean isAvailable() { return customer == null; }  

  //add other methods
}

class Slot {
  private Reservation[] reservations = new Reservation[numberOfSlots]; 
  //properly initialize "reservations" so that it doesn't only contain null elements
  //add other methods
}
```

And in your code you check the number of available reservations per slot (ideally cache that number per slot if you have a larger number of reservations).

Comment: I only need to remaining capacity, so no extra class needed (its not allowed anayways). My biggest problem is, that the capacity and the number of slots are not set variables.. so I could have an array with {1,1} or {1,1,1,1} or {3,3} and I don't know how I could increment them where its needed.

Comment: @v_uztel well, using `int[]` with the elements describing the available capacity it shouldn't be that big of an issue. I assume you're taking user input to get the number of slots and the capacity for each slot (all the same?) so something like `int[] slots = new int[numberOfSlots]; for(int i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) { slots[i] = initialCapacity; }` should work (and if the user needs to enter a capacity per slot just ask for additional input inside the loop.